# Не срабатывает код php

Tags: php, html

Доброго времени суток!
Только начал изучать php, и столкнулся с следующей проблемой:
Имеется файл login.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Kappa</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form aсtion="login.php" method="post">
        <p>login:</p>
        <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="login">
        <p>password:</p>
        <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="password">
        <input type="submit" value="Ввод">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

И файл login.php:

```
<?php 
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    echo 'test';

    $dbconn = pg_connect('host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=kappa user=$login password=$password');

    if (!$dbconn) {
        echo('Ошибка!');
    }
?>
```

По моей логике, он должен вывести ошибку при вводе неверного логина и пароля, но при отправке формы ничего не происходит. В чем проблема?

Comment: `В чем проблема?` - например в том, что ты написал одинарные кавычки в строке подключения, а должны быть двойные.

Answer (score 0):

Замените кавычки как сказал комментатор.

Потом попробуйте включить отображение ошибок

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Возможно у Вас [не подключена](http://php.net/manual/ru/pgsql.installation.php) библиотека для работы с PostgreSQL.

Скорее всего, что PHP не видит функцию соединения (она не определена без библиотеки) и падает с ошибкой, которая просто не отображается.

Answer (score 0):

Все гораздо проще, у тебя в коде *a**с**tion* кириллическая буква, вместо ее латинской сестры